# How to create new columns using data from the column inside the DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the next DataFrame:

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'AAA', 'pn':"[{'code_1': 'green'}, {'code_2': 'link'}, {'code_3': '10'}]"}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'BBB', 'pn': "[{'code_1': 'blue'}, {'code_2': 'link'}, {'code_3': '15'}]"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
```

[image]

I need to create two new columns and for example new column `df['color'] =` ..., new column `df['link'] =` ... and it should be like this, thanks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this :

```
import ast

df['color'] = df.pn.map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)[0])
df['link'] = df.pn.map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)[1])
```

`ast.literal_eval` is used to convert the string into an actual python list and then we select the element we want :)

Edit : In the case that the keys are out of orders :

```
import ast

df['pn'] = df.pn.map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))

df['color'] = df.pn.map(lambda x: [el for el in x if list(el.keys())[0] == "code_1"])
df['link'] = df.pn.map(lambda x: [el for el in x if list(el.keys())[0] == "code_2"])
```

First, you transform the values in the `pn` column in python lists.
Second, you go through the new column and find the dictionary with the right key !

Have a nice day,

Gabriel

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Yes, it works, but what if the order of the value in the list is different, the values are not in order?

Comment: @Alex I edited my answer to take into account an unordered list !

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what you're asking:

```py
df2 = ( df.assign(
    pn=df.pn.apply(eval)).explode('pn').pn.astype(str)
    .str.extract("'([^']*)'[^']*'([^']*)'") )
df2[0] = df2[0].map({'code_1':'color', 'code_2':'link', 'code_3':'code_3'})
df2 = df2.pivot(columns=[0])
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(None)
df2 = ( df2.drop(columns='code_3').assign(
    color = df2.color.map(lambda x: "{" + f"'code_1': '{x}'" + "}"), 
    link = df2.link.map(lambda x: "{" + f"'code_2': '{x}'" + "}")) )
df2 = pd.concat([df[['id','name']], df2], axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
   id name                color                link
0   1  AAA  {'code_1': 'green'}  {'code_2': 'link'}
1   2  BBB   {'code_1': 'blue'}  {'code_2': 'link'}
```

Answer (score 0):

My original answer did not take into account the order of the list being different.

I am assuming that the keys in the dictionaries are consistent, i.e. code_1, code_2 etc.
In order to take into acouunt a different ordering of the list you could do this.

```py
list_ = df["pn"].apply(lambda x: x.strip("[]").split(", "))
df["color"] = [dict_ for mapping in list_ for dict_ in mapping if "code_1" in dict_]
df["code"] = [dict_ for mapping in list_ for dict_ in mapping if "code_2" in dict_]
df.loc[:, ["id", "name", "color", "code"]]
```

If you create a new dataframe with the items out of order

```py
a = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'AAA', 'pn':"[{'code_1': 'green'}, {'code_2': 'link'}, {'code_3': '10'}]"},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'BBB', 'pn': "[{'code_2': 'link'}, {'code_1': 'blue'}, {'code_3': '15'}]"},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'CCC', 'pn': "[{'code_3': '15'}, {'code_2': 'link'}, {'code_1': 'red'}]"},
    
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

Which would look like

```py
    id name  pn
0   1  AAA   [{'code_1': 'green'}, {'code_2': 'link'}, {'code_3': '10'}]
1   2  BBB   [{'code_2': 'link'}, {'code_1': 'blue'}, {'code_3': '15'}]
2   3  CCC   [{'code_3': '15'}, {'code_2': 'link'}, {'code_1': 'red'}]
```

You would get this output:

```py
    id  name  color                 code
0   1   AAA   {'code_1': 'green'}   {'code_2': 'link'}
1   2   BBB   {'code_1': 'blue'}    {'code_2': 'link'}
2   3   CCC   {'code_1': 'red'}     {'code_2': 'link'}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Yes, it works, but what if the order of the value in the list is different, the values are not in order?